# Update wordpress slug when updating post via wpuf pro

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

I'm trying to find a way to **update a custom post type slug** when **editing** post: i need the slug to be **identical** (*sanitized*, obviously) to the **title**.

Custom post is created and edited with **wpuf pro**.

I'm trying to update post via *wpuf_edit_post_after_update* hook, but with no luck.

I'm now using this function **inside my plugin**:

```
function my_set_permalink_as_title($post_id, $post) {
if ( 'my_cpt' !== $post->post_type ) return;

$title = sanitize_title_with_dashes($post->post_title);

$my_post = array(

    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_name' => $title
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );

}

add_filter( 'wpuf_edit_post_after_update', 'my_set_permalink_as_title', 10, 2 );
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just an idiot.

$post object simply doesn't exist inside my function: I have to create it.

I also have removed if statement for clarity.

```
function my_set_permalink_as_title($post_id, $post) {

$post = get_post($post_id);

$askb_title = $post->post_title;
$askb_slug = sanitize_title($post->post_title);

$my_post = array(

    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_name' => $askb_slug,
    'post_type' => 'my_cpt',
    'post_title' => $askb_title,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
);
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );

}
add_filter( 'wpuf_edit_post_after_update' , 'my_set_permalink_as_title' , 99, 2 );
```